# Добавление вложенных коллекций в представлении (view) EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, view

Интересует следующий вопрос, как добавить вложенные коллекции в представление? Например, есть Contracs и Stages - таблицы (связь 1->*) и создано представление ViewContracts для отображения договоров на форме с итогами. 
Можно ли в представление передать коллекцию Stages? 
Добавлено виртуальное свойство

```
public virtual ICollection<Stages> Stages { get; set; }
```

Но не понимаю как передать в коллекцию нужные данные.

Comment: Если вы создали вьюху с описанием так называемого отношения с другой таблицей в виде `JOIN`, то вам нужно описать простое не виртуально свойство и в момент запроса указать таблицу для включения в выборку через `Include`, хотя вполне вероятно, что в случае `virtual` EF всё же поймет, что нужно будет подтянуть по требованию (на представлении не проверял `virtual`).  Вот тут написано вполне понятно: [Relationships](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/query-types#relationships) Всё это сработает, если вы в контексте прописали `DbQuery`, и в `OnModelCreating` указали для типа представление

Comment: @DenisBubnov Начала погружаться, и есть вопрос: у меня насоздано много представлений с расчетом балансов и итогов для представлений пользователю и они подтягиваются в проект как  DbSet. Правильно я понимаю, что это следовало бы организовать в DbQuery и собирать представление в программе?

Comment: @DenisBubnov хотя в примере создается представление в БД create view OrderHeaders.

Comment: Да, правильно представления писать не в `DbSet`, а в `DbQuery`. В примере представление создается немного криво. Я могу лишь рекомендовать вам сгенерировать пустой скрипт на миграцию через `Add-Migration` и в методе `Up` написать скрипт в Sql инъекции через `migrationBuilder.Sql(@" ... ")` в котором будет создание вьюхи, а в методе `Down` - скрипт на ее удаление. Лично мне такой подход больше по душе, чем тот, который описан в примере.

Comment: @DenisBubnov к сожалению миграции пока в очереди на изучение, это немного позже. Хотела уточнить, в БД представления как сущности должны присутствовать? или можно их генерировать LiNQ в новые классы? Тут я понимаю у меня пробел с пониманием.

Comment: @DenisBubnov сейчас на изучении Тролсен, может быть еще посоветуете материал по теме?

Comment: Там всё просто, главное, что нужно знать - это несколько команд и некоторые правила по коду и самим командам. Для начала вам хватит `Add-Migration` и `Update-Database`, всё остальное по мере поступления знаний. Тролсен - хорош, прям вэри гуд. Из меня советник не особо хороший, можно Джона Скита почитать, если будет время, я в свое время почитывал.

Comment: @DenisBubnov подскажите, а конструкция modelBuilder.Query<> поддерживается? Изучаю материал по теме https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types и рекомендованном ресурсе

Comment: @DenisBubnov я правильно понимаю что это решение, если применяется EF Core?

Comment: Да. я как раз это использовал в проекте с `EF Core`

Comment: @DenisBubnov а с EF 6 не было аналогичных задач? Переход я так поняла глобальный из-за отличий

Comment: Скажу честно, что на `EF 6` я не создавал вьюшки таким образом, ну точнее говоря я их создавал, но надобности не было в том, чтобы затянуть их в `DbQuery`, не было необходимости, но не так давно проект сменился и теперь я на `EF Core` уже как года полтора. Вот что-то есть про квери: [DbQuery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). Вообще, думаю, что все можно сделать: [Fluent API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties)